# Display all categories from one site and only a specific category from another site in Expression Engine MSM

Tags: expressionengine

I'm using ExpressionEngine's multisite manager and I'm displaying channel entries from two of the sites - our global site and our localized site for our Australia office. For the Australia site I would like to display all channel entries, but from the Global Site channel entries I would like to only display channel entries from a particular category (in this case "25" ie. those tagged as pertaining to Australia on our Global site).

If I use something like this below, it wont show the any of the entries from the Australia site (tpi_au) because I don't have those categorize.

{exp:channel:entries channel="success" dynamic="no" site="tpi_hq|tpi_au" category="25"}

Is there a way to make that category="25" apply only to tpi_hq?

Sorry this is probably a really easy answer or I'm just doing something totally wrong to begin with... :/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to do this directly in a single channel call.

Situations like this arise all the time, not just with MSM.  What if you want 10 entries for category X and 7 entries from category Y? Same deal.

Basically you need to make two `channel:entries` calls.

If you don't care about the order of the entries you are done. If it bothers you that the `tpi_hq` entries are always at the top of the list while the `tpi_au` entry is always at the bottom then you need to figure a way to sort them.

Two approaches I've used for this:

1. Sort the entries on the client side.  I've done this in jQuery using html5 data-date parameters on `<li>`s.
2. Muck around with passing forward the entry ID's as embed variables.  This requires a total of 3 EE `channel:entry` tags plus an embed so it is definitely less efficient on the server side, if you are concerned about such things.

Incidentally, most of the EE questions are now handled in the [EE SE](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/). You might get a different/better answer over there.